# Import CSS not working in Static Resource

Tags: static-resources

I am trying to import CSS within a CSS file, from a static resource folder. But it shows an error and none of the style in displayed on page.

[image]

Also, the folder is not displayed in Source folder in Chrome Console. Although, I have added the `importCSS` folder in the same directory as of `css` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your path is not correct. When you use a css from static resources in VF page the code will look like this `<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.stylesheet_red}"/>`. The equivalent html code is something like this `<link href="/resource/1235794002000/stylesheet_red" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`.

I think what you can do is use `<apex:stylesheet` and get the equivalent path `/resource/XXXXXXXX/` and try to use this path in css file to import other css. I hope this will work. Please test and let me know.